# Alternate tiling around a cone/curve (Rocket hull)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I am aiming to (non-destructively) model this tiling pattern:

[image]

This requires curving the plates in two axes, tapering them, and offsetting to get that alternating tile pattern.

So far I can array a plate along a curve in one axis:

[image]

But I'm not sure what the best next steps are. Ideally I would be able to control the shape of the cone with a curve (unless anyone knows a better way of getting that shape), and could change how many tiles there are per ring, how many rings, and the taper via modifiers.

(Credit to NeoPork on Twitter for the renders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by non-destructive, but you could try it this way:

Create the pattern:

[image]

Array it on the X and Z axis:

[image]

Bend it 36° with the *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode):

[image]

Give it its final rocket shape with a *Mesh Deform* or a *Lattice* cage:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that effect is exactly what I'm going for, but when I try to bend with simple deform I get more of a solid wedge rather than it cylindrifying nicely like that, is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: for Simple Deform don't forget to apply the rotation of your object, also choose the Bend option and the Z axis, please tell me if it works?

Comment: I tried that and wasn't able to get it to work, but using another object as the origin and rotating that it fixed it, so thank you very much for your help!

Comment: maybe share the blend file that doesn't work so that I can take a look? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/e5d3b9706e42460db2c2d5af7c0fb1f4

Comment: it's just an alignment on good axis, to clean it rotate 90° on the Z axis so that the object is aligned with the X axis, apply the rotation, correct the array modifiers axis and you're good

Comment: In that case I just get a smaller wedge with all the plates stacked in front of each other: https://pasteall.org/blend/e5d3b9706e42460db2c2d5af7c0fb1f4

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, have you followed exactly the steps I describe? Because it works fine, with the last file you share as well

Comment: Ahh I had misread your comment and forgot to change the array modifier axis. All fixed now, thank you!